# C++: Optimization causing weird behavior (stuck in a while-loop which doesn't have it's condition met)

Tags: c++, optimization, while-loop

I've had this problem for a few days now, and haven't found the cause of it. Whenever I build and run my program in debug mode, everything runs fine, however, release mode (with optimization, it works fine without) is a whole other story.

How the program works is that I have one thread waiting for a member variable called (bool) pipeReady to be set to true before continuing, and I have another thread which handles pipe connections and after opening a connection it'll follow a callback to a function which sets pipeReady to true.

When following this by stepping through the program, it acts extremely weird (skips lines, jumps over lines, goes back a few lines), but in the end everything seems to work like it should, except for *one* thing: [this](http://puu.sh/gwbQU/cfaf6cf940.png). It stays in that loop even though it's conditions aren't met. I know that this might not be the best way to handle this, but it *should* work, shouldn't it? How can this happen? What could lead to something like this? And why does it only happen when optimization is on?

Thanks, André

If the link is broken in the future, it shows the debugger being stuck on this line:

```
while(!pipeReady){};
```

While pipeReady's value is true according to the debugger.

Comment: No code, psychic debugging skills needed.

Comment: `pipeReady` should probably something like a semaphore or condition variable. `volatile` doesn't save you, if you should get that idea BTW.

Comment: I can add a lot of code, but according to the debugger everything's working fine prior to getting stuck in those loop, so I don't really know what code to add since this program consists of thousands of lines.

I know having it as a bool isn't the best solution, but is it the cause to this?

Comment: Make `pipeReady` an `std::atomic<bool>` .

Comment: @AndréT. Obviously you can't access that flag concurrently from various threads. You either need a `std::atomic<bool> pipeReady;` or any other appropriate synchronization mechanism for safe access to this flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Weird Debugger Behavior

The weird behavior of the debugger skipping lines is due to the optimizations by the compiler.

When the compiler generates new code or eliminates code, the source line numbers will not align.  This confuses the IDE and shows the Debugger jumping around.  For example, if there are multiple returns from a function, the compiler may issue a branch to the first one for the other returns.  This causes a step to the one return statement, which is not according to the source code.

### Elimination of empty loops.

The compiler may eliminate empty loops like this one:

```
 while (!pipe_ready)  
 {
 }
```

Because the variable is not changed inside the loop.

**To fix this, declare the variable `pipe_ready` as `volatile`.**

Comment: `volatile` does not (by the standard, VC has an extension) do what you think it does.

Comment: Both this and using std::atomic<bool> solved it. It seems like using an atomic is the standard way, so I'll do that. Thanks for the answers; this is something I've been trying to solve for many hours, but haven't been able to!

Comment: In the example above, the `volatile` keyword would indicate that the value of `pipe_ready` is determined outside of the function that the variable is declared in.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews "This makes volatile objects suitable for communication with a signal handler, but not with another thread of execution". Source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv

Comment: @RichardCritten: The volatile value could point to a hardware register, such as the status register in a UART.    The UART will change the value of the status register when it receives a character or transmits one.  Thus the variable is volatile since the hardware is changing the value unbeknownst to the program.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Completly true. But the OP wrote: "and I have another thread which handles pipe connections and after opening a connection it'll follow a callback to a function which sets pipeReady to true.", which is thread not hardware.  So your answer is not correct for the question (except for MSVC which extends the meaning of volatile).